# Component Services Security Settings question

Tags: windows-server-2003, database, com+

I am getting the error "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator" when performing a query that uses a database link.

I have asked our Sys Admins to make the following changes (see URL) to our Component Services configuration, specifically the security settings:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fix-new-transaction-cannot-enlist-in-the-specified-transaction-coordinator-on-server-2003-sp2/

These changes are to a server that is behind the corporate firewall. I am trying to anticipate what possible objections our Sys Admins may have  be to making this change, since it appears to be loosening security.

Can anyone give me some insight into understanding the risk involved in making this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both machines that are going to be involved in the distributed transactions win2003 machines?  If so, you can use the mutual authentication option instead of the No Authentication option.  If one or both of the machines are win2000, then mutual authentication is not possible.

Also, "Allow Remote Administration" probably does not need to be checked off.

See this link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510(WS.10).aspx

These two things may help put your sys admin at ease a bit.

Comment: It looks like the change will require starting and stopping the MS DTC service. Since this is on a production server, I assume that this means that doing so can stop any application that utilizes distributed db operations. I presume that there is no way to tell if any of the 75 dbs on our server uses MS DTC and if I will effect them , which means I have to request that the chg be performed during a scheduled outage, meaning I will be waiting weeks or months to get my change in.

Please comment if you think I am missing an important fact. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, restarting the DTC could cause issues for applications using distributed transactions.  Under the "My Computer" section of the component services configuration, there is a subfolder for the DTC.  Under this, you can see any active transactions and view some transaction statistics.  This may help you and the sys admin decide if restarting the DTC will be detrimental to any other apps.  Other than that, only you guys can decide when to restart.